# how to return true to parent filter loop from child each loop on collection laravel

Tags: laravel, loops, filter

```
$products = $category - > products;

foreach($params as $key => $item) {

    if ($key === 'attribute') {

        $attributes = $item;

        // dd($attributes);

        foreach($attributes as $subkey => $value) {

            // dd($subkey, $value);

            $attr_ids = ProductAttribute::where('name', $subkey) - > pluck('id') - > toArray();

            // print_r($attr_ids);

            // dd($attr_ids);

            foreach($attr_ids as $attr_id) {

                $filtered_products = new Collection();

                $filtered_products = $products - > filter(function($item) use($attr_id, $value)

                    {

                        // echo $attr_id;

                        $item - > characteristics - > each(function($charac) use($value)

                            {

                                // print_r($charac->value);

                                // dd($value);

                                return in_array($charac - > value, $value);

                            });

                    });

                $products = $filtered_products;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I'm developing a filter.
after retrieving products by category
I'm looping through params url(which is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dariy?attribute[size][0]=xs&attribute[rang][0]=black&property[color][0]=green&property[color][1]=tomato`)

in DB, I have got a table of products,productCharacteristics, and productAttributes.

I'm retrieving ids of attributes by name which are given in params(key).

productCharacteristics is being retrieved by relationship.

while I go through the product's characteristics, I check each characteristic's value against in value from params.

if right I should return true to filter. but here is where I'm stuck.
inside filter closure there's each that's why I can't return directly to filter.
How can I do that?

I'm

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($params as $key => $item) {
            
            if ($key === 'attribute' && !empty($item)) {

                $filtered_products = new Collection();
                $attributes = $item;
                // dd($attributes);
                foreach ($attributes as $subkey => $value) {
                    // dd($subkey, $value);
                    $attr_ids = ProductAttribute::where('name', $subkey)->pluck('id')->toArray();
                    // print_r($attr_ids);
                    // dd($attr_ids);
                    $attr_status = false; // assume there's no match
                    foreach ($attr_ids as $attr_id) {
                        $filtered_products = $products->filter(function ($item) use ($attr_id, $value, &$attr_status)
                        {
                            // assume product can't pass filter
                            $item->status = false;
                            $item->characteristics->each(function ($charac) use (&$item, $value, $attr_id)
                            {
                                // product characteristic's attribute_id and charac value  match set to tru to return to filtered prducts
                                if($attr_id == $charac->attribute_id && in_array($charac->value, $value)){
                                    $item->status = true;  // now product can pass.
                                    return true;
                                }

                            });                                                
                            if ($item->status === true) {
                                $attr_status = true;
                                return true;
                            }else{
                                return false;
                            }                      
                        });
                        // setting there's a match for this filter.
                        if ($attr_status) {
                            continue 2; // skipping to next filter
                        }

                        
                    }
                }
                $products = $filtered_products;

            }
}
```

1. in first level of each closure I set a variable `$attr_status = false` so the each filter keeps going on.
   2.in every product attribute checked the value and attribute id do match or not
   if yes $product goes in the filter and I set `$attr_status = true;`
   so the filter cycle can be skipped.